# How can I help translating Ubuntu One Client for Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-one, language-support, translation

I know it is a beta, but it is planned some workaround for translations? I recognize that it will very hard to translate it via Launchpad (it is a WPF C# app) but, any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Beta was an initial proof of concept that we used to test if the solution was possible. After the beta there has been a lot of work trying to get the code used on Linux to Windows, and at the moment we are very close.

At the moment the code is mostly shared between the Linux version and the Windows version with a lot of development being done. When we made the move from C# and WPF (for way to many reasons to explain here) to python we decided to use Qt + gettext so that the translations could be done in launchpad.

So in summary, you can do the translations in Launchpad and we would be grateful for your help. The projects you can take a look at to translate are:

[lp:ubuntuone-control-panel](https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel) (ready to be translated)

[lp:ubuntu-sso-client](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-sso-client) (ready to be translated)

[lp:ubuntuone-windows-installer](https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-windows-installer) (not much work done just yet)

On each page, there is a link under the "Get Involved" heading that provides information for assisting with translations.

I hope the info helps you.